# Implementing WMI-related module from Vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to add this module from other Visual Basic program i found, into my C# program.

I tried to convert it but i am getting errors: CS1061, CS0428, CS1579
while compiling it. Also added references (MS.VB, Sys.Management).

VISUAL BASIC:

```
Public Shared Sub KillLastProc()
    Dim objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\" & Environment.UserDomainName & "\root\cimv2")
    Dim colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
    Dim wmiQuery As String = String.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", "explorer.exe")
    Dim searcher As Management.ManagementObjectSearcher = New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery)
    Dim retObjectCollection As Management.ManagementObjectCollection = searcher.Get
        For Each retObject As Object In colProcess
            If retObject.CommandLine.ToString.Contains("--CMD=") Then
                retObject.Terminate()
            End If
    End Sub
```

CSHARP:

```
public static void KillLastProc()
{
    var objWMIService = Interaction.GetObject("winmgmts:" + @"{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\" + Environment.UserDomainName + @"\root\cimv2");
    var colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process");
    string wmiQuery = string.Format("select CommandLine from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", "explorer.exe");
    System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
    System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection retObjectCollection = searcher.Get;
    foreach (object retObject in colProcess)
    {
       if (retObject.CommandLine.ToString().Contains("--CMD="))
           retObject.Terminate();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.get?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: When you post about errors you're getting, please provide the **exact, full error message**. We shouldn't have to Google the error codes to figure out what the problem is -- you have the full error message on the screen right in front of you, and it's simple to copy/paste them into your question so we have that information. Please [edit] to include them; they're part of the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You have various reasons for your compiler errors. Additionally, the original VB code has unnecessary WMI calls.

Before addressing the WMI code, I would recommend you use the .Net `System.Diagnostics.Process` class to work with processes in C#.

```
Process
    .GetProcessesByName("explorer")
    .Where(x => x.StartInfo.Arguments.Contains("--CMD="))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Kill());
```

In regard to the WMI code, you would accomplish the task as follows:

```
string wmiQuery = string.Format("select * from Win32_Process where Name='{0}'", "explorer.exe");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmiQuery);
var processes = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject retObject in processes)
{
    foreach(var prop in retObject.Properties)
    {
        if (prop.Name == "CommandLine" && prop.Value.ToString().Contains("--CMD="))
        {
            retObject.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
        }
    }
}
```